# Not able to install gazebo ros and its plugins in ubuntu 22.04 ros 2 humble on m2 mac via UTM hypervisor

Tags: gazebo

I almost tried all of the solutions to install gazebo11 on my VM. I even tried to install gazebo fortress but was unable to use it . I need to use gazebo and rviz for specific task for a robot contest.I am a beginner in ROS and robotics in general .Please help me with the installation of gazebo. I have provided by requirements.sh file(2nd pic ) below .[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what instructions you are trying to follow. When you ask questions remember that we only have as much context as you write down. For example please explain what the "all solutions" you tried are. And where the requirements.sh you are trying to execute comes from. It's best to provide enough information for people to reproduce your problem.

Regardless the best recommendation is to follow the official installation instructions for ROS Humble here

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

After you have set up that you will have all ROS Humble binary packages available as well as both gazebo11 and gazebo(nee ignition) fortress.